# Reset wrong file permissions on root directory

Tags: command-line, 18.04

I accidentally changed my file permissions for the root directory ( / ) and now I am unable to do pretty much anything. What I ran was

```
sudo chmod 70 /
```

I am running Ubuntu desktop 18. I tried running a live cd to fix the permissions but that didn’t work. What can I do to repair this mistake?

Comment: Does `sudo chmod 0750 /` still work? If not, booting in recovery mode or from a live system might help.

Comment: No sudo commands work. I just get permission denied when I try anything sudo.

Comment: Thought so. Well, in this case you'll have to boot a live system, mount your root filesystem and fix the permission this way.

Comment: You have stirred your system with a `root`stick. There is only backup your data and reinstall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this using recovery mode. I booted to the most recent kernel in recovery mode. The I selected the option to drop into a root shell. I then ran

```
mount -o remount, rw /
chmod 755 /
```

After I rebooted and allowed it to boot on its own (most recent kernel with normal mount) the / directory had the correct permissions.